# Check if a sentence contains multiple words in a row (Python)

Tags: python, contains, cpu-word, sentence

I want to write a function that checks if a given sentence contains given words. For example:

```
my_string = 'Biden'
sentence = 'Biden is the new president of the United States.'

if my_string.lower() in sentence.lower().split():
    print('Sentence contains string')
else:
    print('Sentence does not contain string')
```

This example would return True. Now a problem arises once the string isn't just a single word.

```
my_string = 'Joe Biden'
sentence = 'Joe Biden is the new president of the United States.'

if my_string.lower() in sentence.lower().split():
    print('Sentence contains string')
else:
    print('Sentence does not contain string')
```

Here it would return False. Is there simple solution for this problem?

Answer (score 2):

You could use a regular expression - the thing you're looking for encapsulated by word-boundaries:

```
import re

word = "Joe Biden"
pattern = f"\\b{word}\\b"

sentence = "Joe Biden is the new president of the United States"
match = re.search(pattern, sentence, re.IGNORECASE)

print(f"Sentence {('contains', 'does not contain')[match is None]} string")
```

Comment: Thanks for your answer, it works perfectly! Often times I try to avoid regular expressions though because it's usually fairly slow (afaik and I can't get it to be faster) so do you know if there's a way to get this line of code to work faster or maybe just another solution without it?

Comment: It's true that, compared to other possible solutions, a regex will be *relatively* slow. Though I wonder, if a regex is actually "too slow" for your use-case? If your actual use-case isn't much more complex than this, and doesn't require an insane pattern, I wouldn't worry about doing any premature optimizations. At the moment, I can't think of any other cute solutions that wouldn't involve regexes.

Comment: The function here is actually just a smaller part in a big project which involves a much larger number of words and sentences unfortunately

Answer (score 1):

Try

```py
my_string = 'Joe Biden'
sentence = 'Joe Biden is the new president of the United States.'
my_string = my_string.split()
sentence = sentence.split()
confirm = []
for i in sentence:
  if i in my_string:
    confirm.append(i)
if confirm == my_string:
  if sentence.find(my_string) != 0 - 1:
    # my_string is in sentence
    pass
```

This should work with your problem and your various requirements.

Original:

```
my_string = 'Joe Biden'
sentence = 'Joe Biden is the new president of the United States'
if sentence.find(my_string) != 0 - 1:
  # my_string is in sentence
  pass
```

Comment: Hi, thanks for your answer! Your solution definitely solved the issue in my example but if there's somthing like: 

my_string = 'Unite'
sentence = 'Joe Biden is the new president of the United States.'

It would still return True, which I don't want my function to do.

Comment: Well there is another long solution, I’ll edit it in...

Comment: Thanks, the issue is solved! But there's another problem for my use case now: If there's a string like 'Biden president' it would return True, but I only want a string to return True if it appears in exactly that order in the given sentence.

Answer (score 0):

Try that:

```
    my_string = 'Joe Biden'
sentence = 'Joe Biden is the new president of the United States.'

if my_string.lower() in sentence.lower(): 
    print('Sentence contains string')
else:
    print('Sentence does not contain string')
```

Comment: Depending on the use case this might not be the best solution. For example, if you were searching for "bypass" in the string "By passing it over.." your code would instead search for "bypass" in the string "bypassingitover..." and would resolve to true.

Comment: @Befeepilf I agree. Thanks.
I updated my suggestion.

Comment: Unfortunately this solution would return True on a string like 'Unite' which I don't want